# How to exactly align two equilateral triangles to make a six-pointed star in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two equilateral triangles, one pointing up and one pointing down. I created the triangles using the polygon tool.

- Sides: 3
- Radius: blank
- Smooth Corners: unchecked
- Star: unchecked

I need to align these triangles exactly to make a six-pointed star.

I can do so visually by manually moving the stars but I presume the alignment is inexact.

I specifically need to make the star this way rather than using the polygon tool because I need to be able to work with each triangle in isolation.

Comment: The question is a bit wague. You have triangles fine but how are the triangles made? Thats kindof critical. You may find though that illustration tasks like this are way easier in Illustrator, mainly because photoshop does not have the snappingtools of illustrator. Yeah, this is most likely faster to to do in illustrator even if you never used it.

Comment: @joojaa I've added a list elaborating on how I created the triangles using the polygon tool. I'll try aligning the triangles in Illustrator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a math formula to actually calculate things exactly... but here's how I'd do it quickly....

Center align both triangles and place a guide where they intersect horizontally...

[image]

Move the top-point triangle down until the top hits this guide... Then place a second guide where the triangles intersect again.

[image]

Calculate *half* the distance between these two guides and place a third guide...

[image]

Align the bottom of the top-pointed triangle with this third (middle) guide.

[image] [image]

---

You can also bisect each side with a perpendicular line aligned with the opposite point. Do this for each side and you get the center point of the triangles. Then merely align the center points.

[image]

---

Either method works for this star....

[image]

Comment: The center of a triange is at its bisectors crossing. Or putting it another way the center coordinate of a triange is the average of their vertex coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw an equilateral triangle, and drop a vertical guide to bisect it, zoom in for accuracy
2. Draw a line down this guide, and group both line and triangle

[image]

3. Duplicate the group, and rotate the group while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to constrain the angles, and reposition it by nudging with the arrow keys to get the two triangles to overlap as close as possible

[image]

4. Drop a horizontal guide where the two centre lines intersect. Zoom in to get it accurate

[image]

5. Rotate the triangle group back, and reposition by nudging with the arrow keys. Drop a vertical guide to the left/right to make sure they align.

[image]

6. Hide the line layers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No handy enough snappings in Photodhop, but a workaround exists.

Draw a triangle with the Polygon tool. Hold Shift to get it straight:

[image]

Scale it to the right size. Scale proportionally (=hold Shift when dragging) a little to get the numbers ON in the infobar, but then set the proportionality switch ON and type the wanted height as an easy number. I typed 900 px to the height field.

Duplicate the shape layer, change the color as you like and flip the duplicate vertically by applying Edit > Transform Path > Flip Vertical:

[image]

Elementary math (skipped here) can show that to get the perfectly symmetric star you must move one of the triangles vertically exactly one third of the triangle height. I moved 900/3 pixels upwards i.e. -300 pixels.

[image]

The legacy Photoshop doesn't have such transformation as Move in Edit > Transform Path collection. But clicking Scale opens in the infobar also the shape placement fields. I checked the "Relative positioning" option and typed to the Y-field -300px.

**Not asked:** In a vector drawing program you'd draw a hexagon and then draw by clicking only with the pen 2 triangles between hexacon's cusps. The pen snaps exactly if you have relevant snap to points ON. The next screenshot is from Inkscape. In Illustrator you must rotate the hexagon 30 degrees because holding Shift as one draws the hexagon makes one of the sides horizontal.

[image]